I keep getting this, Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'
I an trying to make and app, this is my code, it's not done yet
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation
struct ContentView: View {

    
    @State var qwerty = "202"
    @State var Title = "This is your Puppy, you need to give him food and water every 1 hour and take him on walks every 2 hours."
    @State var Hunger = "10"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text(Title)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            
            
            
            Image("HappyPuppy")
            
            while qwerty == "202" {
                
               Text("Hunger is " + Hunger)
                
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Feed") {
                if Hunger < "10" {
                    Hunger = Hunger + "1"
                }
            }
            
            Button("Give water") {
                
            }
            
            Button("Walk") {
                
            }
            
            Button("RESET") {
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

I tried almost everything but I can't get the loop to work.
I anteing to make it so when you click the "feed" button the displayed Hunger variable goes up by 1 and it starts on 10. Ignore the rest of the code, the app is far from finished.

In a SwiftUI View body, it is expected to have only other Views.
Some are constructed (from closures using @ViewBuilder) based on
simple control flows like if and if else,
but not complex ones like while and for loops. It is just the way SwiftUI is made.
Try using if instead of while to achieve the same logic. If you need to loop over many items, then use ForEach. See also ViewBuilder
